# How can I delete 1 selected row from a lot of tables in PHP (from mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP function, to write out my tables from MYSQL. I've made a button, to delete the selected rows (named torles).

How can I delete with my 'torles' button, the row in which I'm pressing it?

```
function munkalapok(){
  kapcsolat();  //connect to mysql, and write out all rows

  $sql="SELECT * FROM munkalap ORDER BY id DESC";
  $vissza=mysql_query($sql);
  mysql_close(kapcsolat()); //close mysql

  print "<div class='datagrid'><center>";
  print "<table border='1' align='center'>";
  print "<thead><th>Módosítás</th><th>Munkalapszám</th></thead>";

  $i='1'; //for count rows
  while ($sor = mysql_fetch_array($vissza)) {
    print "<tr><tbody>";
    print "<form method='POST'>".
          "<input type='submit' value='$i. Törlés' name='torles'>".
          "</form>" . "</td>";
    //Create the button
    if(isset($_POST['torles'])){
      kapcsolat(); //open mysql
      $parancs="DELETE FROM munkalap WHERE munkalapszam = '$munka'";                 
      mysql_query ($parancs);
      mysql_close (kapcsolat());
      header("Location: ./Munkalapok.php");
    }
    print "<td>" . $sor['munkalapszam'] . "</td>";
    print "</tbody></tr>";
    $i++;
  }
  print "</table>";
  print "</center></div>";
}
```

Comment: Have you got a primary setup in the table? If so, you would need something to relate this to the UI, so you can determine which one to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `$munka`, how did you get this..may be it should be for id..

So you can have a hidden field in your form and make it value as row id(whatever you have)

just try as:

```
print "<tr><tbody>";

print "<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$sor[munkalapszam]'><input type='submit' value='$i. Törlés' name='torles'></form>" . "</td>";
    //Create the button
if(isset($_POST['torles'])){

kapcsolat(); //open mysql
$munka=(int) $_POST['id'];  //i did this for id
$parancs="DELETE FROM munkalap WHERE munkalapszam = '$munka'";                 
mysql_query ($parancs);
mysql_close (kapcsolat());
```

may this help you

Comment: $munka is "munkalapszam" from the database. It's a unique id for rows.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you do something like this:

```
connect to SQL, get rows and print them
while printing
  show a button
  if this button is pressed, delete a row and redirect
end while
```

This is your first error.
Instead, your code logic should look something like this:

```
if there is posted data
  delete the data
connect to SQL, get rows and print
```

Your main problem, (the one you are asking about), is that you create buttons, but no way to identify which row the button was pressed in.
Instead of adding the $i variable in the value of the button, you can add another input, which is hidden:

```
print '<input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="'.$i.'"/>';
```

This way, you will be able to find out which row the button was pressed for:

```
if (isset($_POST['torles'])) {
  $id = (int) $_POST['row_id'];
  // delete where id = $id (assuming that $i is an id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IDs to identify records on your database? You should associate an ID to each record with the autoincrement function. That will be your Primary Key. Then use the record ID to identify the table row, and do not use that $i variable.

You should check out Database's Normal Forms. http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Comment: Yes, I'm use IDs, but I didn't wanted to write out that to this page.
The "munkalapszam" value is unique too, like the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you have an id for every element in your db. And that the id is a primary key.
Saying that, modify

> `print "<td>" . $sor['munkalapszam'] . "</td>";`

to

```
print "<td>" . $sor['munkalapszam'] . "<span id='".$sor['id']."' >X</span></td>";
```

In this way, every row in your table can be uniquely identified.The **X** is the delete symbol.

Next step would be to use JS to handle the click and sent the id to the server using ajax to delete the row.

```
$( "td" ).click(function() {
   //write the ajax code here to send the id to the server.
});
```

This is not the most secure way to do this. But this would give you a basic idea on how to get started.

you can read about jQuery ajax here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
jQuery click event : http://api.jquery.com/click/

In the backend you need a file called as delete.php or soemthing.Write the logic to delete a row using **id** in this file.Pass the **id** as argument through ajax to this.